# WiFi Drops When SIM Inserted

Tags: wi-fi

When I insert SIM card in my ZenFone 5, it WiFi is disconnected and stucks on "Serching for WiFi..." and don't show any WiFi. I think its because of WiFi regional code. I live in Iran. How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be WiFi region code problem or something.

I also had the same problem. My parents live in Iran and when I brought the phone to Malaysia, it's fixed. But when I sent it back, same thing happened after they inserted the SIM card.

I found a link that might be useful, it might help: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.majidse.xwifix. I still haven't tested it yet though.